# How to execute statements in order in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i tap on my button, my function was called

```
[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In my function, a collection of complex statement will be executed and take a litte bit time to run, so i want to show Loading (UIActivityIndicatorView) as the following:

```
-(void) addTradeAction {
    //Show Loading
    [SharedAppDelegate showLoading];

    //disable user interaction
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    //execute call webservice in here - may be take 10s
    //Hide Loading
    [ShareAppDelegate hideLoading];
}
```

When tap on myBtn (my Button) -> after 3s or 4s, [ShareAppDelegate showLoading] was called.

It is unusual when i use [ShareAppDelegate showLoading] on other Function, -> it work very nice, i mean all the statement be executed in order.

All i want, when i tap on My Button, Loading will be called immediatelly.

Tks in advance

Comment: Show the code for `myFunction`. Is everything running on the main thread?

Comment: use blocks with completion handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct way to perform a tasks in background, and in your case showing an activity indicator, is :

```
-(void)myBackGroundTask
{
    //here showing the 'loading' and blocking interaction if you want so

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //here everything you want to perform in background

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            //call back to main queue to update user interface
        });
    });
}
```

With this kind of block, you are sure that your interface do not freeze, and keep a smooth animation.

Answer (score 1):

If your complex statements do not any UI animations or UI related code, then you can execute that part in a different thread(other than the mainThread). Once the statements are done(or in completion block), you can remove the loadingOverlay there.

Answer (score 0):

Put myFunction to run on a background queue as it probably makes the system hang:

```
- (void)myFunction {
   dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

    // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
       // Put the current myFunction code here.
    });

}
```